# PythonでOandaAPIのtrades.TradeCloseにおいてのエラー

Tags: python

```
from oandapyV20 import API
from oandapyV20.exceptions import V20Error
import oandapyV20.endpoints.trades as trades

# OANDAのデモ口座へのAPI接続
api = API(access_token=access_token, environment="practice")
r = trades.TradeClose(accountID=accountID, tradeID=9, data=5000)
api.request(r)
print(r.response)
```

決済したいため以上のコードを実行したところ、

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "oanda.py", line 51, in <module>
    api.request(r)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oandapyV20/oandapyV20.py", line 306, in request
    request_args, headers=headers)
  File "/Users/.pyenv/versions/3.6.1/lib/python3.6/site-packages/oandapyV20/oandapyV20.py", line 243, in __request
    response.content.decode('utf-8'))
oandapyV20.exceptions.V20Error: {"errorMessage":"Invalid JSON body, must be an object"}
```

以上のようなエラーがでました。
原因はどのように考えられますか。

よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 質問の際は他のユーザーが現象を再現できるような必要最小限のコード、及び実行環境の情報(使用しているライブラリなど)を含めてください。 - [良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) / また、何かAPIを呼び出しているようなので、ある程度はご自身でマニュアル等を読み解いてもらう必要があります。 http://developer.oanda.com/docs/jp/

Comment: `api.request(r)`の前に`print("REQUEST:{}".format(r))`を追加したら、何が出力されますか？

Comment: api.request(r)の前にprint("REQUEST:{}".format(r))を追加すると、REQUEST:v3/accounts/accountID/trades/9/closeが出力されました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/164829